# JavaScript URL without localhost

Tags: javascript, url

I am new to JavaScript and I want to write JavaScript scripts which will works without "localhost" and port etc.

Here is the example of my code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8081/trainer/testToUser",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

And I want something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "trainer/testToUser",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

(This variant does not work)

Which will work without with any port for example. I read about "window.location", should I use something like this?

Comment: When you look at the request in the Network tab, what does the URL look like? That might tell you why it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a slash at the beginning and it will take the request's origin domain.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/trainer/testToUser",
    dataType: "json",
    ...
```